# Windows Universal App Bluetooth Low Energy Connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app

I am working on a project which requires Windows Universal Apps to communicate with a BLE device. I am trying to find a way in which I can see how Bluetooth Low Energy devices can be scanned, paired and send/receive data.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to specifically access the bluetooth-low-energy protocol (as in, the default methods use the old high-energy protocol)?

Comment: I want to know how to scan, connect, disconnect and get data from the sensor.

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.aspx) namespace can be used to pair devices via [DeviceInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.pairing.aspx).[Pairing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationpairing.aspx).[PairAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationpairing.pairasync.aspx) and the [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270288.aspx) namespaces can be used for connecting and advertising

See MSDN's [Pair devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt608997.aspx) documentation for an overview of pairing.
See MDSN's [Bluetooth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270288.aspx) page for an overview of RFCOMM, GATTand LE Advertisements.

The [GATT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185618.aspx) docs walk through retrieving Bluetooth LE data and controlling LE devices.

The [Bluetooth advertisement sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) demonstrates watching and publishing LE advertisements from both the foreground and background.

Also check out the Build 2015 session[Building Compelling Bluetooth Apps in Windows 10](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-739)

Answer (score 1):

This information, originally written for Windows 8, should also work for the Windows 10 universal platform. These functions have a C++ context, but they should be accessible from other languages.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj159880(v=vs.85).aspx